# Magento 2 reindex process stuck on Category Products and Product Categories

Tags: magento2, reindex

I am working on Magento 2.3.2. I am doing reindex but the process is never ends for `Product Categories` and `Category Products`.

I tried to reset these both and tried to reindex one by one. But nothing worked. It is just showing processing. No error or anything.

Can anyone help me how to complete reindex for these both ?

Comment: same here, any solutions ?